# Spring Data Jpa query by method name do not work correctly with BETWEEN for LocalDate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables: "DailyStatistic" with ManyToOne to "Country".

```
public class DailyStatistic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate date;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;
```

///

```
public class Country {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue
            private Long id;
            private String name;
```

When I call:

```
public interface DailyStatRepository extends JpaRepository<DailyStatistic, Long> {
...
List<DailyStatistic> findAllByCountryAndDateBetween(Country country, LocalDate from, LocalDate to);
...
}
```

I get strange result:

```
2020-03-29
2020-03-28
2020-03-27
2020-03-30
2020-03-29
```

Hibernate sets to object a wrong date and I get two different objects with the same date.

Please, help to solve the problem.

The code where I call this method:

```
public class DataProvider {

    private final ForeignDataSource foreignDataSource;
    private final DailyStatRepository repository;
    private final CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DataProvider(ForeignDataSource foreignDataSource, 
                        DailyStatRepository repository, 
                        CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        this.foreignDataSource = foreignDataSource;
        this.repository = repository;
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

public List<DailyStatistic> getCountryStatFromToDate(Long countryId,
                                                         LocalDate from,
                                                         LocalDate to) throws NoDataException {
        Country country = countryRepository.findById(countryId).orElseThrow(NoDataException::new);
        List<DailyStatistic> dailyStatisticList = repository.findAllByCountryAndDateBetween(country, from, to);
        for (DailyStatistic ds : dailyStatisticList) {
            System.out.println(ds.getDate());
        }
```

Comment: Please include the code which calls this query.  Also, check the source data in your table.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, thank you for answer. Done. In DB everything ok. Tried to do the same with simple sql query in a console and resultSet was correct.

Comment: `Hibernate sets to object a wrong date and I get two different objects with the same date` is `DailyStatistic.date` field unique in db ?

Comment: Please add the query executed from application log

Comment: @Abinash Ghosh, no, it is not. There are many records for different countries with the same date.

Comment: See what query executed in log. And for every country date is unique right ?

Comment: @Abinash Ghosh, omg, there are going on something awful) Log is too long, I copy it to there -> https://codeshare.io/alezyj . Is it problem n + 1, or something else?

Comment: @Abinash Ghosh, in db a date is unique for every country, but it is not a restriction.

Comment: please check table data using query Line 194 to  200, is it ok or not. Please add controller and service also

Comment: @Abinash Ghosh, service is DataProvider, it is present in a description. I test it. With this sql query below it is work fine. How Can I do the same query with method name in JPA? -> SELECT *
from daily_statistic as d
INNER JOIN country as c
ON d.country_id = c.id AND c.name = 'USA'
 WHERE d.date BETWEEN '2020-03-25' AND '2020-03-30'
ORDER BY d.date DESC

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jpa method naming for `DailyStatistic` filter by country name and date

```
repository.findAllByCountryNameAndDateBetweenOrderByDateDesc(country.name,from, to);
```

Answer (score 0):

How I figure out it happens because of a different timezone on app side and db side + daylight saving time that happened on April 29. So if someone get similar issue - check a timizone difference at first.